# Cordova & iOS Simulator Incredibly Slow?

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to make an app with `Cordova`, but the problem is whenever I build it and it uses the simulator function (this is for `iOS` by the way), it takes a long time to load. Like almost `10 minutes`. `Ctrl + T` is not on, so I don't know why it's taking so long. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yes, `cordova` take more time to load in simulator then `iOS native app`! It is normal, but it is majorly depend on your mac's configuration! If you have high computing device (mac) then it shouldn't take that much time (as you mentioned 10 minutes)! So, it's depends on your mac's configuration! And yes cordova will definately take little more time than ios native app, so if your cordova app is not taking much more time than native app then it is nothing like an issue!